# Terminal locking up trying to import scapy.all

Tags: python-3.x, freeze, scapy

Everything else in python seems to work. When I start python from my terminal and type `from scapy import all` it completely locks up on me and takes a minute or two to kill. Anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Do you kill it with `Ctrl-C`? Can you attach the stack trace?

Comment: Error messages? No errors appear, it just hangs and locks up so that it's difficult to kill. Ctrl-C doesn't even work.

Comment: Try inserting `pdb` before the import statement and stepping into it until you find the problematic line.

Comment: Timeouts of this size are often related to I/O errors and retries. E.g. a DNS lookup or something, or removable storage misbehaving. BTW does `Ctrl`+`Z` and then `kill %1` work any faster? (If you're inclined, you could [use gdb where the process hangs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb)).

Comment: Hmm Ctrl+Z and kill seems to work immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to provide extra information (OS, python version, scapy version, pcap lib uses (if any)...) so that we can provide more complete answers

Note that latest scapy versions (2.4.0) must be imported via

```
from scapy.all import *
```

You may also try the latest [dev github version](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip), which has great enhancements

Finally if nothing works, feel free to report a bug on the [github page](https://github.com/secdev/scapy)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly why, but here are a few possibilities:

1. it might be working, but taking a while to import; you can check this by watching the CPU usage.
2. give it a few minutes and if it's still not working hit ctrl-c as Austin said; it should display an error trace which could tell you where the program is caught up.
3. Your version of `scapy` might be out of date (the latest is 2.4.0). Try updating to the newest version

Comment: Thanks. Tried it on another computer and it imported in about 2 sec, let it go on the first and 20 min later its still hanging.  Pip says I'm using the latest version.

Comment: in that case, all I can think of is that another program/module is stopping scapy from running properly.